# Auto comment all public members in a file

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xml-comments

I have turned on warnings as errors and now i need to XML comment all of my public methods.

just to get my program compiling, i just want to put placeholders for now.

Is there anyway to automatically add XML comments to all of the public members in a class or  a file.

I see ghost doc which gives you good autogenerated XML comments but it still looks like it only does one member at a time.

Comment: I think placeholders are a bad idea. They'll never get filled in.

Comment: @ooo: did you ever find the tool you were looking for? I see GhostDoc does that with their licensed version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could turn off the specific warning for the lack of comments with [/nowarn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f28x9z3(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the Xml comments until you have completed adding them in.

Or you could write an app to generate them for you. Or use a code snippet.